# Adding margins to button object programatically

Tags: android, android-button

Need to set left margin to a button object programatically.
This is the code segment:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.for_button);
MarginLayoutParams ml = new MarginLayoutParams(-2,-2);
ml.setMargins(5, 0, 0, 0);

Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setText("7");
btn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.date_button);

rl.addView(btn,ml)
```

I also tried

```
btn.setLayoutParams(ml);
rl.addView(btn);
```

Whats the big problem. Or is there any alternative way?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Doesn't work? Dimension not correct? *(also note that you only set a 5px margin on one side, thats pretty small, easy to miss when looking at the layout)*

Comment: what is the problem ? your code is not working or what ?

Comment: sorry that i forgot to mention that specifically.Problem is Margins not set when i run this.....above code supposed to add margin to the left first in the `ml` then for the button right? but its not happening....

Comment: @alextsc i give a sample margin as 5... actually the margin is incremented per iteration of a _for-loop_, like first iteration 45, second iteration 45*2 , i think thats quite noticeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a RelativeLayout as the parent for the button, but you don't specify any rules for the it where to place the button *(e.g. `ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT` and `ALIGN_PARENT_TOP`)*.

You *have* to set rules for position when using a RelativeLayout though, so this messes with the layout calculation. This means that you have to use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` instead of the `MarginLayoutParams` because the former allows these rules and has proper default values set.

Alter this line:

```
MarginLayoutParams ml = new MarginLayoutParams(-2,-2);
```

to

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ml = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(-2,-2);
```

Chances are that you also want to add rules because the default positioning values don't suit you *(views get positioned in the top left corner of the parent layout by default)*. You can use [`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.addRule()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule%28int%29) for that.

Comment: thanks, if i were you i would think that i gave my best. peace and a hi5 thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I'm gonna give this a shot IronBlossom; this is how I do it and I hope it works:

```
LinearLayout myLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_linear_layout);
Button myButton = new Button(this);
// more myButton attribute setting here like text etc //

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
params.setMargins(5,0,0,0);
myLinearLayout.addView(myButton, params);
```

best,

-serkan

Comment: Also, if you want to edit a View which is already made you can do something like, view.getLayoutParams(), instead of instantiating a new LayoutParam object.  This should preserve any previous layout rules.