# In Android, how do I set margins in dp programmatically?

Tags: android, android-button

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481455/set-margins-in-a-linearlayout-programmatically), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981456/setting-buttons-margin-programmatically) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312215/adding-margins-to-button-object-programatically) thread I tried to find an answer on how to set the margins on a single view. However, I was wondering if there isn't an easier way. I'll explain why I rather wouldn't want to use this approach:

I have a custom Button which extends Button. If the background is set to something else than the default background (by calling either `setBackgroundResource(int id)` or `setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable d)`), I want the margins to be 0. If I call this:

```
public void setBackgroundToDefault() {
    backgroundIsDefault = true;
    super.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
    // Set margins somehow
}
```

I want the margins to reset to -3dp (I already read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914039/margins-of-a-linearlayout-programmatically-with-dp) how to convert from pixels to dp, so once I know how to set margins in px, I can manage the conversion myself). But since this is called in the `CustomButton` class, the parent can vary from LinearLayout to TableLayout, and I'd rather not have him get his parent and check the instanceof that parent. That'll also be quite inperformant, I imagine.

Also, when calling (using LayoutParams) `parentLayout.addView(myCustomButton, newParams)`, I don't know if this adds it to the correct position (haven't tried however), say the middle button of a row of five.

Question: Is there any easier way to set the margin of a single Button programmatically **besides using LayoutParams?**

EDIT: I know of the LayoutParams way, but I'd like a solution that avoids handling each different container type:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams p = this.getLayoutParams();
    if (p instanceof LinearLayout.LayoutParams) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)p;
        if (_default) lp.setMargins(mc.oml, mc.omt, mc.omr, mc.omb);
        else lp.setMargins(mc.ml, mc.mt, mc.mr, mc.mb);
        this.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
    else if (p instanceof RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)p;
        if (_default) lp.setMargins(mc.oml, mc.omt, mc.omr, mc.omb);
        else lp.setMargins(mc.ml, mc.mt, mc.mr, mc.mb);
        this.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
    else if (p instanceof TableRow.LayoutParams) {
        TableRow.LayoutParams lp = (TableRow.LayoutParams)p;
        if (_default) lp.setMargins(mc.oml, mc.omt, mc.omr, mc.omb);
        else lp.setMargins(mc.ml, mc.mt, mc.mr, mc.mb);
        this.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
}
```

Because `this.getLayoutParams();`returns a `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`, which do not have the attributes `topMargin`, `bottomMargin`, `leftMargin`, `rightMargin`.
The mc instance you see is just a `MarginContainer` which contains offset (-3dp) margins and (oml, omr, omt, omb) and the original margins (ml, mr, mt, mb).

Answer (score 975, accepted):

You should use `LayoutParams` to set your button margins:

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
yourbutton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Depending on what layout you're using you should use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` or `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.

And to convert your dp measure to pixel, try this:

```
Resources r = mContext.getResources();
int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
        yourdpmeasure, 
        r.getDisplayMetrics()
);
```

Comment: From which package should I import that particular LayoutParams?

Comment: note that your conversion is the wrong way, from dp -> px. I needed the other way around. But I already have a solution.

Comment: setMargins used px and you will use dp, my conversion is right : dp -> px to set correct margin value.

Comment: @ChristiaandeJong RelativeLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: @stoefln  Why RelativeLayout.LayoutParams and not LinearLayout.LayoutParams?

Comment: it depends of your current layout. If you are in LinearLayout, use LinearLayout.LayoutParams. RelativeLayout.LayoutParams otherwise

Comment: You can use your concrete type or use MarginLayoutParams as Lyusten suggested. It is the base class for all Layouts.

Comment: you should import layoutParams that is your parent layout
ex. <linearlayout><relativelayout><gridlayout> and you are working with grid layout. then, you need to use relativelayout.layoutparams

Comment: btw what is wrong with using `(int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.my_dp);` to find the dp value

Comment: getDimension si to get the dimension of known Ressources defined in your resources folder, here it's to get the dimension of another resources not defiend in the resources folder

Comment: What if I'm using FrameLayout as the parent layout? There's no setMargin in FrameLayout.LayoutParams.

Comment: @stealthjong , take its parent layout.

Answer (score 294):

LayoutParams - NOT WORKING ! ! !

Need use type of: MarginLayoutParams

```java
MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams) vector8.getLayoutParams();
params.width = 200; params.leftMargin = 100; params.topMargin = 200;
```

Code Example for MarginLayoutParams:

http://www.codota.com/android/classes/android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams

Comment: Correct, but no need to set it back, the changed params are automatically reflected. Thus you can remove the line: vector8.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: LayaoutParams usually create confusion while setting margin... So this MarginLayoutParams is very useful. Thanks

Comment: you DO need to setLayoutParams(params) after marging changes

Comment: i found MarginLayoutParams  as new class today #Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't work for `Button` view: `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams()` returns `null`

Answer (score 156):

Best way ever:

```
private void setMargins (View view, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    if (view.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        p.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
        view.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

How to call method:

```
setMargins(mImageView, 50, 50, 50, 50);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i am facing issue when i **set setMargins(holder.vCenter, 0, 20, 0,0);** like this 
its leave margin both sides (top and bottom) whats wrong with above params?

Comment: why do we need `requestLayout()` ?

Answer (score 50):

```
int sizeInDP = 16;

int marginInDp = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, sizeInDP, getResources()
                    .getDisplayMetrics());
```

Then

```
layoutParams = myView.getLayoutParams()
layoutParams.setMargins(marginInDp, marginInDp, marginInDp, marginInDp);
myView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Or

```
LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams...
layoutParams.setMargins(marginInDp, marginInDp, marginInDp, marginInDp);
myView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: what is getResources()?

Answer (score 50):

With [Android KTX](https://android.github.io/android-ktx/core-ktx/androidx.view/android.view.-view-group/update-layout-params.html), you can do something like that:

```
yourView.updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
   setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 27):

## Here is the all-in-one answer with recent updates:

**Step 1, to update margin**

The basic idea is to get margin out and then update it. The update will be applies automatically and you do not need to set it back. To get the layout parameters, simply call this method:

```
LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) yourView.findViewById(R.id.THE_ID).getLayoutParams();
```

The `LayoutParams` comes from the layout of your view. If the view is from a linear layout, you need to import `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`. If you use relative layout, import `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` , etc.

Now, if you set the margin using `Layout_marginLeft`, `Right`, etc, you need to update margin in this way

```
layoutParams.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
```

If you set margin using the new `layout_marginStart`, you need to update margin in this way

```
layoutParams.setMarginStart(start);
layoutParams.setMarginEnd(end);
```

**Step 2, to update margin in dp**

All two ways of updating margin above are updating in pixels. You need to do a translation of dp to pixels.

```
float dpRatio = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int pixelForDp = (int)dpValue * dpRatio;
```

Now put the calculated value to the above margin update functions and you should be all set

Answer (score 17):

In Kotlin it will look like this:

```
val layoutParams = (yourView?.layoutParams as? MarginLayoutParams)
layoutParams?.setMargins(40, 40, 40, 40)
yourView?.layoutParams = layoutParams
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as the setMargins method takes in only values in pixels and not dp, which is what the user is asking.

Answer (score 10):

layout_margin is a constraint that a view child tell to its parent. However it is the parent's role to choose whether to allow margin or not. Basically by setting android:layout_margin="10dp", the child is pleading the parent view group to allocate space that is **10dp bigger** than its actual size. (padding="10dp", on the other hand, means the child view will make its own content **10dp smaller**.)

Consequently, **not all ViewGroups respect margin**. The most notorious example would be listview, where the margins of items are ignored. Before you call `setMargin()` to a LayoutParam, you should always make sure that the current view is living in a ViewGroup that supports margin (e.g. LinearLayouot or RelativeLayout), and cast the result of `getLayoutParams()` to the specific LayoutParams you want. (`ViewGroup.LayoutParams` does not even have `setMargins()` method!)

The function below should do the trick. **However make sure you substitute RelativeLayout to the type of the parent view.**

```
private void setMargin(int marginInPx) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
    lp.setMargins(marginInPx,marginInPx, marginInPx, marginInPx);
    setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

This method will let you set the **Margin** in **DP**

```
public void setMargin(Context con,ViewGroup.LayoutParams params,int dp) {

        final float scale = con.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        // convert the DP into pixel
        int pixel =  (int)(dp * scale + 0.5f); 

        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams s =(ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)params;
        s.setMargins(pixel,pixel,pixel,pixel);

        yourView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can change the parameter that suits your need.

Answer (score 10):

With Kotlin you can use the `View.updateLayoutParams` extension function:

```
yourView.updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
    setMargins(15,15,15,15)
}

// or

yourView.updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
    topMargin = 15
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**You can use this method and put static dimen like 20 it converts according your device**

```
 public static int dpToPx(int dp) 
      {
          float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
       return (int) (dp * scale + 0.5f);
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

### Simple Kotlin Extension Solutions

Set all/any side independently:

```
fun View.setMargin(left: Int? = null, top: Int? = null, right: Int? = null, bottom: Int? = null) {
    val params = (layoutParams as? MarginLayoutParams)
    params?.setMargins(
            left ?: params.leftMargin,
            top ?: params.topMargin,
            right ?: params.rightMargin,
            bottom ?: params.bottomMargin)
    layoutParams = params
}

myView.setMargin(10, 5, 10, 5)
// or just any subset
myView.setMargin(right = 10, bottom = 5)
```

Directly refer to a resource values:

```
fun View.setMarginRes(@DimenRes left: Int? = null, @DimenRes top: Int? = null, @DimenRes right: Int? = null, @DimenRes bottom: Int? = null) {
    setMargin(
            if (left == null) null else resources.getDimensionPixelSize(left),
            if (top == null) null else resources.getDimensionPixelSize(top),
            if (right == null) null else resources.getDimensionPixelSize(right),
            if (bottom == null) null else resources.getDimensionPixelSize(bottom),
    )
}

myView.setMarginRes(top = R.dimen.my_margin_res)
```

To directly set all sides equally as a property:

```
var View.margin: Int
    get() = throw UnsupportedOperationException("No getter for property")
    set(@Px margin) = setMargin(margin, margin, margin, margin)
   
myView.margin = 10 // px

// or as res
var View.marginRes: Int
    get() = throw UnsupportedOperationException("No getter for property")
    set(@DimenRes marginRes) {
        margin = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(marginRes)
    }

myView.marginRes = R.dimen.my_margin_res
```

To directly set a specific side, you can create a property extension like this:

```
var View.leftMargin
    get() = marginLeft
    set(@Px leftMargin) = setMargin(left = leftMargin)

var View.leftMarginRes: Int
    get() = throw UnsupportedOperationException("No getter for property")
    set(@DimenRes leftMarginRes) {
        leftMargin = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(leftMarginRes)
    }
```

This allows you to make `horizontal` or `vertical` variants as well:

```
var View.horizontalMargin
    get() = throw UnsupportedOperationException("No getter for property")
    set(@Px horizontalMargin) = setMargin(left = horizontalMargin, right = horizontalMargin)

var View.horizontalMarginRes: Int
    get() = throw UnsupportedOperationException("No getter for property")
    set(@DimenRes horizontalMarginRes) {
        horizontalMargin = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(horizontalMarginRes)
    }
```

> NOTE: If margin is failing to set, you may too soon before render, meaning `params == null`. Try wrapping the modification with `myView.post{ margin = 10 }`

Answer (score 8):

That how I have done in `kotlin`

```
fun View.setTopMargin(@DimenRes dimensionResId: Int) {
    (layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams).topMargin = resources.getDimension(dimensionResId).toInt()
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to add a margin to your TextView you will have to LayoutParams:

```
val params =  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
params.setMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
your_view.layoutParams = params
```

LayoutParams can be any layouts like Relative, Linear, View or ViewGroups. Choose the LayoutParams as you need. Thanks

Comment: op asked for margins

Comment: I mentioned both padding and margin. I think you misunderstood. I hope you read my whole answer properly! @anshsachdeva

Comment: yes, my bad. its now 2 days since i commented, so i can't change my -1.  kindly make edits to your answer to highlight the actual solution  and i will change it :)

Comment: @anshsachdeva, I have updated the answer of mine. Let me know if it's helpful or not. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use this method to set margin in dp

```
private void setMargins (View view, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    if (view.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

        final float scale = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        // convert the DP into pixel
        int l =  (int)(left * scale + 0.5f);
        int r =  (int)(right * scale + 0.5f);
        int t =  (int)(top * scale + 0.5f);
        int b =  (int)(bottom * scale + 0.5f);

        p.setMargins(l, t, r, b);
        view.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

call the method :

```
setMargins(linearLayout,5,0,5,0);
```

Comment: Simply simple!. Thanks

Comment: Simply done. Worked Perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

When you are in a custom View, you can use `getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dimen_value)`, in my case, I added the margin in LayoutParams created on `init` method.

In Kotlin

```
init {
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, this, true)
    layoutParams = LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT).apply {
    val margin = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dimen_value)
    setMargins(0, margin, 0, margin)
}
```

in Java:

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {

    //..other constructors

    public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        int margin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.spacing_dime);
        params.setMargins(0, margin, 0, margin);
        setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Working utils function using DP for those interested:

```
public static void setMargins(Context context, View view, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    int marginLeft = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, left, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int marginTop = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, top, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int marginRight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, right, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int marginBottom = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, bottom, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    if (view.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        p.setMargins(marginLeft, marginTop, marginRight, marginBottom);
        view.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on other answers, i made a generic extension function, which identifies your parent and uses the params accordingly:

```
//takes margin values as integer , eg for 12dp top , you will pass 12
fun View?.setMarginFromConstant(mLeft:Int, mTop:Int, mRight:Int, mBottom:Int){
    this?.apply {
        val left = context?.dpToPixel(mLeft)?:0
        val top = context?.dpToPixel(mTop)?:0
        val right = context?.dpToPixel(mRight)?:0
        val bottom = context?.dpToPixel(mBottom)?:0
        when (val params = this.layoutParams) {
            is ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams -> {
                params.marginStart = left
                params.marginEnd = right
                params.topMargin = top
                params.bottomMargin = bottom
            }
            is FrameLayout.LayoutParams -> {
                params.marginStart = left
                params.marginEnd = right
                params.topMargin = top
                params.bottomMargin = bottom
            }
            is RecyclerView.LayoutParams -> {
                params.marginStart = left
                params.marginEnd = right
                params.topMargin = top
                params.bottomMargin = bottom
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and

```
fun Context.dpToPixel(dp: Int): Int =
    (dp * applicationContext.resources.displayMetrics.density).toInt()
```

You can add support for other parent view groups too

Answer (score 2):

```
val params = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
)
params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 400)
binding.container.setLayoutParams(params)
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @Lyusten Elder is correct, but don't forget that you need to convert px to dp before doing it.

Like this:

```
    public static int getPxFromDp(Context context, float dp) {
        return Math.round(dp * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }

    public static int getDpFromPx(Context context, float px) {
        return Math.round(px / context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For a quick one-line setup use

```
((LayoutParams) cvHolder.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

but be carfull for any wrong use to LayoutParams, as this will have no `if` statment instance chech

Answer (score 1):

Created a Kotlin Extension function for those of you who might find it handy.

Make sure to pass in pixels not dp. Happy coding :)

```
fun View.addLayoutMargins(left: Int? = null, top: Int? = null,
                      right: Int? = null, bottom: Int? = null) {
    this.layoutParams = ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(this.layoutParams)
            .apply {
                left?.let { leftMargin = it }
                top?.let { topMargin = it }
                right?.let { rightMargin = it }
                bottom?.let { bottomMargin = it }
            }
}
```

Comment: android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams. :(

Answer (score 1):

In my example i am adding an ImageView to a LinearLayout programatically. I have set top and bottom margins to ImagerView. Then adding the ImageView to the LinearLayout.

```
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        params.setMargins(0, 20, 0, 40);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        linearLayout.addView(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to you can set dp correctly:

```
public int dpFormat(int dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
}
```

and then call

```
setMargins(dpFormat(15), dpFormat(15), dpFormat(15), dpFormat(15));
```

Comment: its work for me but maybe there should be getApplicationContext() instead of getContext().

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. hope this helps.
First, create a parameter with height and weight then set margins as per your need then set this parameter to the layout you need.
The `setMargins(0, 0, 0, 150)` function has sequence margins of  (left, top, right, and bottom) respectively.

```java
            ScrollView svOfferDesc = findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            );
            params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 150);
            svOfferDesc.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

As today, the best is probably to use [Paris](https://github.com/airbnb/paris), a library provided by AirBnB.

Styles can then be applied like this:

```
Paris.style(myView).apply(R.style.MyStyle);
```

it also support custom view (if you extend a view) using annotations:

```
@Styleable and @Style
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I was using ViewGroup.LayoutParams in a themedbutton component. So using ViewGroup.LayoutParams unable to use setMargin.

Instead use MarginLayoutParams as below, it worked for me.

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params =new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );
        params.setMargins(0,8,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following code worked

```
buttonLinearLayout.layoutParams as MarginLayoutParams).apply 
{
   top.run { 
        topMargin = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.spacing).toInt() 
     }                        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first create dimens.xml file in values directory and create dimen value on it

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="circle_margin">5dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

then create layoutparams variable and apply on it.

```
 val layoutParams = LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
                layoutParams.setMargins(resources.
    getDimension(R.dimen.circle_margin).toInt())
                layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                binding.imageView.layoutParams = layoutParams
```

Answer (score -1):

```
((FrameLayout.LayoutParams) linearLayout.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(450, 20, 0, 250);
        linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.smartlight_background);
```

I had to cast mine to `FrameLayout` for a linearLayout as it inherits from it and set margins there so the activity appears only on part of the screen along with a different background than the original layout params in the `setContentView`.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.full_white));
setContentView(linearLayout,layoutParams);
```

None of the others worked for using the same activity and changing the margins based on opening the activity from a different menu! setLayoutParams never worked for me - the device would crash every single time.  Even though these are hardcoded numbers - this is only an example of the code for demonstration purposes only.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams` to set the width, height and margins

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginLayoutParams = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
marginLayoutParams.setMargins(0,16,0,16);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(marginLayoutParams);
```

Where the method `setMargins();` takes in values for left, top, right, bottom respectively. Clockwise!, starting from the left.