# Android setMargins not working programmatically

Tags: android, margin

```
<RelativeLayout>

    ...

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:layout_marginTop=”11dp”
      android:background=”@drawable/image”  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then I need to set the Margin programmatically:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewRoot(R.id.imageView1);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
params.width = 100;
params.height = 100;
params.setMargins(0,0,0,0); //NOT WORK
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

The ImageView still has marginLeft 10 and marginTop 11;

What is wrong?

Comment: did your problem was solved?

Comment: No is not. Neither of both answers solved my problem

Comment: Try setting params without getting the old params.

Comment: explain a little more please

Comment: set the margins after the display of dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html) to set margins to your `ImageView`. Here  is a method from [@Hiren Patel answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35199927/4848308) that works perfectly for me.

```
private void setMargins (View view, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    if (view.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        p.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
        view.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Sample of how to use in your code:

```
public void testMargin(View view){
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)   imageView.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = 100;
    params.height = 100;
    setMargins(imageView , 0, 0, 0, 0);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

My test layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    tools:context="com.g2o.test.TestActivity">

    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/cast_ic_notification_0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:onClick="testMargin"
        android:text="Test" />" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: This not work. Dont do anything. Still have the 10 and 11 margin

Comment: Maybe because im changing the size too?

Comment: My parent layout is the Relative Layout. Not have anything of that

Comment: I test your sample and works for me fine. I **edited my answer** with my test layout and my activity, I also add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to fit the ImageView to the real image size to avoid any extra margin. Let me know if this don't works for you.

Comment: Ok, please let me know if you still have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to make a new LayoutParams?

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewRoot(R.id.imageView1);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
params.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: This not work. Nothing happens, still have the same margins

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help put your ImageView in RelativeLayout and set it's width and height to Match-Parent

```
 <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/lay_expandable"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_expansion" />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

and in your activity use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`
for example

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                    (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 400);
            lay_layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

// note expand the relative layout, not the image itself

Answer (score 0):

This can be useful for someone: 
In my case I was dealing with the same problem, that margins was not being recognized on android api 19, so what I did, it was to change the size of the image (increase a bit), and then adjust padding, like follows:

```
file: dimens.xml
<dimen name="image_padding_right">5dp</dimen>
```

then on code:

```
 val imageView1 = ImageView(this.activity)
 imageView1.setPadding(0,0,
 resources.getDimension(R.dimen.image_padding_right).roundToInt(), 0)
 imageView1.cropToPadding = true
```

the opcion **cropToPadding** allows you to do the workaround, in case margins dont work.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Margins sometimes don't work:

```
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
params.width = 100;
params.height = 100;
params.setMargins( 0,0,0,0 );
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Margins working:

```
final ImageView imageView = ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

imageView.post(() -> {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = 100;
        params.height = 100;
        params.setMargins( 0,0,0,0 );
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    });
```

Some Layout paramters have to be set not to early to the ImageView programmatically. For example in "onCreate" is to early. I suspect it is overwritten, but not sure.

So you have to set it later, for example with "ImageView.post()" listener, thats called after drawing. First code snippet is sometimes to early, second is working.

And by the way why use "findViewRoot" to get the ImageView? Just use "findViewById"?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Excuse me, Mister Bot, I am not so good in your native language, so I kept the answer to a minimum. Thank you for putting me in my place. I hope it is better now.