# Imageview on a random position

Tags: java, android

I want myImageView to locate itself somewhere on a random position inside the screen, without pushing textviews away. I found this code in another thread, but I can't get it to work.

```
 myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
        LinearLayout game = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.game);

        int width = game.getWidth();
        int height = game.getHeight();

        random = new Random();

        int x = width;
        int y = height;

        int imageX = random.nextInt(x-50)+50;
        int imageY = random.nextInt(y-100)+100;

        myImageView.setX(imageX);
        myImageView.setY(imageY);
```

Comment: `Math.random()` is your friend.

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is that I don't know what method to use in order to place the imageview on a certain position.

Comment: I just updated the main post with my latest code that I found in another thread. According to them this code should work, but for some reason it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can give margin programmatically between certain range, may be you can use device width or height for range. Check this links for [setting margin dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728255/in-android-how-do-i-set-margins-in-dp-programmatically) on run time and [get screen dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743116/get-screen-width-and-height).

Comment: Looks helpful, but please put the relevant parts to your answer. For now this is a link only answer.

Answer (score 0):

I Think first get programmatically device size then set image view width & height

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
```

hear you get width & height now set image view size

```
android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams =myImageView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.width = 30;
layoutParams.height = 30;
myImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

and if you still have a problem to change it's size try to put it inside of a LinearLayout and manipulate the imageView size using the layout params:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, 30);
myImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: If you already know that you calls are deprecated why don't you provide an alternative call?

Comment: I've tried your solutions but I haven't been able to solve the problem yet. I've tried using setX and setY but I can't get it to work. Here's the code:

Comment: @StephanRogers what you get error??

Comment: I don't get any errors but 50% of the time the imageview position itself outside of the screen. I added the code to the main post.

Comment: @StephanRogers get device width & height then set image view width & height

Comment: I've done that but I can't randomize its position. Please refer to the code that I added to the main post.

Comment: @StephanRogers Remove to your Random method to set image view x & y position use like myImageView.setMaxWidth((width / 2));
 myImageView.setMaxHeight((height / 2));

Comment: But if I remove the Random method the imageview will have the same position all the time.