# How to set margin with dp size in Android

Tags: android

I want set margin for views by **programmatically**, i should set **50dp** for `margin_top`, i use this code

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(searchView.getLayoutParams());
                    marginParams.setMargins(0, 75, 0, 0);
                    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
                    searchView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

but in this code set 50px! how can i set this **50dp**, not px?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Android, how do I set margins in dp programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728255/in-android-how-do-i-set-margins-in-dp-programmatically)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert it:

```
final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int pixels = (int) (dps * scale + 0.5f);
```

Comment: can you edit your codes with my codes ? i want set 50dp

Answer (score 2):

For dimens.xml:

```
context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.view_height);
```

For harcoded value:

```
int height = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50,
               getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int dp(int px) {
    return (int) (px * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
int margin = dp(50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
 /**
 * Convert dp to pixel
 *
 * @param dp
 * @return px
 */
public static int dpToPx(final float dp) {
    return Math.round(dp * (Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private int dp2px(int dp) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

convert it!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **Kotlin** solution

You can use the following function:

```
fun dpToPx(context: Context, dp: Float): Int {
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, context.resources.displayMetrics).roundToInt()
}
```

You could choose to take advantage of extensions instead:

```
// Use: 16f.dpToPx(context)
internal fun Float.dpToPx(context: Context): Int {
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, this, context.resources.displayMetrics).roundToInt()
}
```

Or if using a dimens resource, use the following:

```
context.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.some_dimen_id)
```