# Add margin or padding to RadioButton into a RadioGroup programmatically

Tags: java, android

I would like to add margin or padding to a RadioGroup programmatically but it not working.

**RadioButton:**

```
<RadioButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_fruit"
    android:button="@null"
    android:checked="false" />
```

**RadioGroup:**

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_group"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

</RadioGroup>
```

**Java code:**

```
RadioButton radioButtonView = (RadioButton) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.radio_button, null);

radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView);
```

I tried to use `LayoutParams` and `dividerPadding` but it not works

[image: example]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this

```
  RadioButton radioButtonView = (RadioButton) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.radio_button, null, false);
  RadioGroup.LayoutParams params = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  params.setMargins(15, 15, 15, 15);
  radioButtonView.setLayoutParams(params);
  radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView);
```

Comment: Thank you! It works with a new `LayoutParams`. I tried to get the current `LayoutParams` with `getLayoutParams()` and it was not working. Now it works thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Margin & Padding for a RadioButton:

```
RadioButton rd = new RadioButton(getActivity());
RadioGroup.LayoutParams params = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
rd.setLayoutParams(params);
rd.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
radioGroup.addView(rd);
```

Margin and padding for the RadioGroup are the same, only the type of LayoutParams will be different (not RadioGroup.LayoutParams) but what your RadioGroup's parent layout is: LinearLayout.LayoutParams or RelativeLayout.LayoutParams or FrameLayout.LayoutParams, etc. You get the idea.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
radioGroup.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Left, top, right, bottom are in pixels, so you should transform your DP into PX, like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728255/in-android-how-do-i-set-margins-in-dp-programmatically#answer-12728484)

Comment: Thanks for your post. This completes the answer :-)