# get and set layout_margin java

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I to want get and set margin of my LinearLayout from java. I do not want set like right,left, top, bottom etc. I just want set simple margin from all side. I know I can do it via XML but I do know how can I do it via java.

I have done via xml is like below

```
android:layout_margin="20dp"
```

Anyone can please suggest me how can I do it via java?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728255/in-android-how-do-i-set-margins-in-dp-programmatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Android, how do I set margins in dp programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728255/in-android-how-do-i-set-margins-in-dp-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set margin to the view you can use this code:

```html
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);
```

---

To get the margin of view use this code

```html
View view = findViewById(...) //or however you need it
LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
   // margins are accessible via

lp.leftMargin;
lp.rightMargin;
lp.topMargin;
lp.bottomMargin;

// perhaps ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams will work for you. It's a base class for //other LayoutParams.

ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
```

Note: Sorry for using snippet...
It will work like a charm...

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to do so.

```
 LinearLayoutview ll= findViewById(R.id.linearLayout); //or however you need it
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) ll.getLayoutParams();
```

margins are accessible via

```
lp.leftMargin;
lp.rightMargin;
lp.topMargin;
lp.bottomMargin;
```

Now you can use the code

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
 params.setMargins(20,20,20,20);
 ll.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: First I want know margin of it and want increase or decrease it.

Comment: Have a look now. You can adjust the margin as per your convenience as you got margin.

Answer (score 0):

Need use type of: MarginLayoutParams

Try this:

```
MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams) vector8.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = 200; params.leftMargin = 100; params.topMargin = 200;
```

Code Example for MarginLayoutParams:

http://www.codota.com/android/classes/android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams

Comment: First I want know margin of it and want increase or decrease it.