# How to set RecycleView list item Layout Params programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

In my `RecyclerView` adapter I want to set the top margin of the items depending on their position. I only want items **after the first** item to have a top margin. In my code I set the margin of the `RecyclerView` item programmatically.

When I try to add an item to the `RecyclerView` however, the item is not visible. I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728255/in-android-how-do-i-set-margins-in-dp-programmatically) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481455/set-margins-in-a-linearlayout-programmatically) but my code is still not working. Does it make a difference that I'm setting the margin programmatically inside of a `RecyclerView`? I tried using `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` and `RecyclerView.LayoutParams` but still nothing.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

I was using the following code to convert `dp` to `px`

```
int top = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                    R.dimen.element_row_margin_top,
                    r.getDisplayMetrics()
            );
```

I was passing the RAW dimension value instead of calling:`resources.getDimen()`.

Here is my `onBindViewHolder` code:

```
if (position != 0) {
            
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );

            params.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);
            holder.linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
```

Here is my `rec_list_item` (Contains an `Image` and 2 `TextInputlayouts`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

ViewHolder code:

```
@Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                    int viewType) {

        LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.rec_list_item, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(item);
        return vh;
    }

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public LinearLayout linearLayout;
        public MyViewHolder(LinearLayout item) {
            super(contributorItem);
            linearLayout = item;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to grab the current layout params from the `ViewHolder` LinearLayout before setting the params back; so that you want to change the margin of the current ViewHolder
LinearLayout, not creating a one from scratch in order to keep other params as-is.

So, change the `onBindViewHolder` code to

```
    if (position != 0) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) 
                                                holder.linearLayout.getLayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);
        holder.linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

> **UPDATE:**

Add id to the root LinearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        
        ......
```

Inflate the `linearLayout` using `findViewById` in the ViewHolder not by assignment.

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public LinearLayout linearLayout;
        public MyViewHolder(View item) {
            super(contributorItem);
            linearLayout = item.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout); // <<<<<<< inflating the LinearLayout
        }
    }
}
```

Change the `onCreateViewHolder` to accept a `View` instead of a `LinearLayout`

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                int viewType) {

    View item = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.rec_list_item, parent, false);

    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(item);
    return vh;
}
```

Comment: ahhh. your answer makes sense. Going to try it later.

Comment: hmmmm. just tried your code and it is not working...

Comment: Should I be using `RecyclerView.MarginLayoutParams` or `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams`

Comment: It worked with me .. can you show which `linearLayout` you use .. I see you don't have any IDs for the root element of the list item

Comment: I added an `id` to the root `linear layout`. still nothing. I added more code above. Thank you.

Comment: Ahhh wait a minute! It works! Before passing a pixel value for the margin top I was converting `dp` to `px` - that was causing the problem. I have to fix the conversion code.

Comment: @Izak thanks for comment.. I just updated the answer in `UPDATE` section .. hope it works now