# How many different unit types can you use for setMargins()

Tags: android, kotlin

We know that to set margins this is one way of doing it

I discovered this example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12728484/10334519programmatically). it sets margins in the dp unit type.

```
val param = xml.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
    
param.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom)
    
xml.layoutParams = param
```

This variable i discovered from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9563438/10334519). It translates pixels to dp allowing you to then use it for one of the parameters shown in my previous example.

```
val pxToDP = if ( direction == "left" || direction == "right" ) {
                px / ( xml.context.resources.displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)
            } else if ( direction == "top" || direction == "bottom" ) {
                px / ( xml.context.resources.displayMetrics.ydpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)
            }
```

But what if i want to set margin using a variable that represent inches? How would i do that?

And are there any other methods i can use to set margin in Kotlin where the variable represents a different unit type? If so, what are the methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most often case in Android when setting any dimensions: pixels are used. also `setMargins` get px values, not dps or any other (according to [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams#setMargins(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))). so if you have some number in different unit then you need to convert it to pixels

for re-calculating some value in given unit use `TypedValue` class, e.g. like below:

```
int _10dpInPixelUnit = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10,
            getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

if you want to use inches just use `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_IN` (some doc and other units [HERE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue#COMPLEX_UNIT_IN))