# Command and Property order for "Margin" and "Padding" in Android XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, padding, margin

Lets say you have an ImageView or a Button in an Andriod ConstraintLayout.

I know you can set the "Margin" & "Padding" properties in XML individually with:

```
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

android:paddingStart="1dp"
android:paddingTop="2dp"
android:paddingEnd="3dp"
android:paddingBottom="4dp"
```

But can you set them all with just one line? E.g.

```
android:layout_margin="15,25,20,10"
android:padding="1,2,3,4"
```

And in what order would the properties then come?

- Top, Bottom, Left(Start), Right(End)?
- Left(Start), Top, Right(End), Bottom?

Answer (score 0):

No in XML you cannot set them all in one line.
But you can do that programmatically [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12728484/11136190)