# Command and Property order for "Margin" and "Padding" in Android Java Code

Tags: java, android, layout, padding, margin

I previously asked:
[Is it possible to set the "Margin" and "Padding" in Android XML with just one line each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70945943/property-order-for-margin-and-padding-in-android-xml-code).

... and according to @MikeM.'s comment, it seems like that is not possible to do with XML.

Now to the same question but with Java code instead:

---

Lets say you have an ImageView or a Button in an Andriod ConstraintLayout.

Is it possible to set the "Margin" & "Padding" properties just with one command each in Java code? E.g.

```
layoutParams.margin="15,25,20,10"
layoutParams.padding="1,2,3,4"
```

And in what order would the properties then come?

- Top, Bottom, Left(Start), Right(End)?
- Left(Start), Top, Right(End), Bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the other question is "no" unless you write a custom *ViewGroup* with a custom layout attribute. In general, when all sides are specified in the Android environment, the order of side specification is "left,top, right, bottom." I don't think this is a canonical order but is my observation.

As for changing margins in Java where `lp` is the layout params for a view:

```
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
view.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

See [ViewGroup.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)).

For padding you can use [View.setPadding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setPadding(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)):

```
view.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom)
```

Notice that margins are managed by *ViewGroups* and padding is managed by *Views*.